# Error when testing for the max value of a table?

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, exception, while-loop

I have an error when I try to run a loop that will test the max value of a table.

The table is `tabl` with a length of `c`.

```
int a=0;
int b=0;
while (a<=c) {
    int d = tabl[a];
    int e = tabl[a+1];
    if(d < e)
        b = e;
    else
        b = d;
    a++;
}
```

It's pretty easy, it starts with comparing `tabl[0]` and `tabl[1]`, and saves the bigger one, and then keeps going until `a = c` which is the length of the table and then finishes the loop saving the biggest value of the table in `b`.

But when I run this I get an `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` error code, can anyone help please? thanks!

Comment: If c is the array lenght, in the last loop iteration a == c and you are going outside array capacity with: int e = tabl[a+1]

Comment: If the table is of length `c` then your condition will have to be `while (a < c-1)`, because you need `tabl[a+1]` to actually exist in the array, and the largest index in the array is `c-1`.

Comment: I guess indeed that was my mistake, I am pretty stupid to always forget the -1 and +1s about tables starting from 0, thanks everyone :)

Comment: Your formatting is off and will increase the likelihood of errors.

Comment: A friendly suggestion for future reference; it's much easier for users to understand code if all of the variables used are shown in the code extract, I.E. in this case, `c`, `d` and `e`. Glad you got the bottom of things :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you reach `a = c - 1` in your loop, your code is looking for the value of `tabl[c-1]`and `tabl[c]`. However, since your table is of length `c`, this causes an `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. Beware that in Java, arrays are 0-indexed, that is to say, the first element is at index 0 and the last at index (length - 1).

You could write something like that, using a for-each construct :

```
int max = 0;
for (int element : tabl) {
    if (element > max) {
        max = element;
    }
}
```

or a simple for loop

```
int max = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < tabl.length; i++) {
    int element = tabl[i];
    if (element > max) {
        max = element;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're going out of the bounds of your array when trying to reach `tabl[a+1]` when `a` equals `c`

Your whole algorithm doesn't really make sense: you don't have to compare the current index's value to the next one to find out the max of the array, but rather the current value to the previous maximum value you found out.

A common way to find the maximum value of an array is that one:

```
int max = table[0];
for(int i = 1; i < c; i++)
    if(table[i] > max)
        max = table[i];
```

This way, `max` will contain the highest value of the array (though the code will throw an Exception if the table is empty).

Please, indent your code better, and use more meaningful variable names (people understand `max` better than `b`)

Comment: You are assuming the numbers in the table are positive. It is better to start off with a value actually in the table and iterate through the rest.

Comment: I modified your answer to start iterating at 1. No point in checking the same value twice.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are going one past the end of the array. Arrays are zero indexed, so the item at c is going to be IndexOutOfBounds.

Also because you are accessing a + 1, this means that on the loop when a = c - 2, a + 1 will access the last element of the array.

Try:

```
int a=0;
int b=0;

while (a < c - 1){
    int d = tabl[a];
    int e = tabl[a+1];
    if(d<e) { b=e;} else { b=d; }
    a++; 
}
```

NB: The change is to say a < c - 1 rather than a <= c to ensure that a is never = c when indexing into the array.